# HTML values of div dependant on each-other

Tags: html, css

Please excuse me for the poor title, i don't know how this way of coding in html is called and that's why i made the question in the first place.
I have written some code but i need to know how this *way* of coding is called.

i have a div with the value: "container", also i have another div "container bottom-services". I wrote it that way because i saw that the class bottom-services will user container's styling because i didn't want to use the same css styling for bottom-services, too. Here is the code:

```
<div class="container">
 ...
</div>

<div class="container bottom-services">
....
</div>
```

styling:

```
.container
{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Comment: sorry. but your problem isn't clear for me. can you mention it?

Comment: `container` is a CSS class that is applied to both `div` elements. `bottom-services` is a CSS class that is only applied to the bottom `div` element. The CSS you apply to the `container` class will be applied to both; the CSS you apply to `bottom-services` will only apply to the bottom one. Note that you currently have a syntax error (the comma after `.container`) in your CSS.

Comment: I have seen somewhere that if you want to style 2 different divs the same way, instead of writing (in my case):
.container, .bottom-services
{
 ...
}

in the value of the second div attribute you can write :"the name of the first div and then write the name of the second div class".
Here, the first div is "container", the second is "bottom-services". The way styling of bottom-services depends on the styling of "container" is that i write "container bottom-services" as the value of that 2nd div and this way i can only style .container and that styling will also apply to bottom-services.

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes, i already know that. Excuse the syntax error since i didn't copy-paste correctly. My question is, how is this way of coding in html called, if that makes any sense. F.e: is this some kind of styling inheritance applied to bottom-services? I have a presentation tomorrow and i don't know how this "styling inheritance" is called. I made "styling inheritance" up just for clarification.
Thank you for answering.

Comment: You can [edit] your question to remove typos if that's not what your question is about. You should also be clear that you're looking for the name for the concept. I wouldn't use the term inheritance; that [has a specific meaning in CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Cascade_and_inheritance#Understanding_inheritance).

Comment: @HereticMonkey thanks for the suggestions and the critic. I tried to make sure that the question i have is clear by writing it on the first sentence of the description. Since i can't find how this **concept** is called, i guess i will just explain the point of it tomorrow. 
Thank you for your time.

Comment: I would think the concept is simply: `multiple classes` or maybe `chaining`. Since the initial user styled state will follow the "global" `.container` styles, then it's "chained" with further styles that may or may not override the original class properties. @HereticMonkey curious on your thoughts about that.

Comment: @disinfor "Multiple classes" describes what it is. "Chaining" is a bit of a stretch. Brings to mind method chaining or optional chaining in other languages, which is something, in my mind, quite different. But don't let me be the arbiter here -- I'm no wordsmith, I just volunteer here :).

Comment: @HereticMonkey ahh, that makes sense from an "other language" perspective. I think the concept can just be that "multiple classes" - I think it's hard to separate what has been ingrained for so long (for some of us) into a separate concept. I just like to pick the brains of other SO users I see often, like you, Temani, Michael_B, j08691, etc. Thanks for taking the time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you wrote class doesn't have a special meaning

it's how css works on class...

but if you look about some of **css architectures**

> you are very close of **BEM methodology**

it's great scaling css and a little deeper than your described

take a look at this link for more examples :
https://seesparkbox.com/foundry/bem_by_example

another Methodologies you can look for and compare :

- OOCSS
- SMACSS
- SUITCSS

Answer (score 1):

I feel like there isn't a universal term, but the example above follows the concept of what I'd like to call Modular CSS so that you would have less CSS rule-sets by composing small rule-sets declared from multiple classes.

Answer (score 1):

method chaining might not be close to the answer, at this moment there isn't something that specifically describes this multiple-class css styling.